# Why is wp_is_post_revision always false?

Tags: custom-post-types, revisions

I am trying to save a revision of a custom post type. This is what I have to check if the post has a parent:

```
function save_revision( $post ) {

    if ( $post['submitted'] == true ) {
       $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post['post_id'] );
       ...
    }
} add_action('init', 'save_revision');
```

The problem is that I always get false for $parent_id even though I know there is a parent post for that post_id.

Any help is appreciated, I have been trying to get this to work forever.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but for future reference - the term "revision" in Wordpress is a little confusing. It's not the updated, *or revised*, post... but the older version. The most updated version is the "parent."

So, if you're calling the function `wp_is_revision_post()` on the current version of the post, it will always return `false` (and `wp_get_post_parent_id()` will return `NULL`) since the current post is not considered a "revision." You will need to call it on an actual revision, (which would have a different ID from the current version of the post).

Answer (score 1):

It is simple: If `$post` is not a revision, `wp_is_post_revision()` returns false; just reading the name of the function give you the reason. `wp_is_post_revision()` returns the parent post ID only if the given post is a revision (a revision has always a parent post). It seems that you want to get the parent post ID of `$post`, not checking if `$post` is a revision.

To get the parent post ID of another post use [`wp_get_post_parent_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id):

```
function save_revision( $post ) {

    if ( $post['submitted'] == true ) {
       $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post['post_id'] );
       ...
    }
}
add_action('init', 'save_revision');
```